# Tec-tus 1 immobilizer programming

Tags: immobilizer

I have a tec-tus 1 immobilizer, mounted later in my Landcruiser in Germany, possibly from the last century.

It has a sensor with a red LED. It reads ordinary RFID-fobs; I have actually tried putting the cat with its ID-chip-implant to the sensor, and it reads something is there. However, for practical reason I have not added the cat to the known fobs ;-)

I now need to add another fob, but I have lost the manual, and forgotten how.

[image]

Comment: Do they still exist? Do they have a website? Tech support?

Comment: I've mailed, and got an out-of-office autoreply "I'm out of office until Wednesday 2018" ;-) Perhaps somebody here could answer faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out the alarm was not made by tec-tus, only the transponder.

I emailed the right company, and got a reply rather early in the morning with pdf's with schematic and programming.

Basicly the procedure is:

1. Close doors.
2. Ignition on, then off
3. Touch transponder with red master fob (for about 3 sec) until led flashes quickly.
4. Remove fob for about 1-2 sec
5. Touch again. Led goes solid, then flashes quickly again
6. (If you want to delete existing fobs, touch with a known fob. Light goes solid, then flashes quickly again)
7. For each fob, touch until light goes steady for 1 sec and flashes again.
8. Ignition on and off ends programming.

[The german manual is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6OyvlZi3reSOXZ4UEdyWmRJWHF5QUsyUUhDRTBYVE9RMFJj/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write out your answer, and for providing us with the procedure and the link to the manual!